# Eliminar item de un ListView desde un Adapter

Tags: java, android

Tengo una actividad la cual tiene un ListView.
Los items del ListView tienen un TextView y un ImageButton.

La idea es que cuando se hace click en el ImageButton abra un AlertDialog y si se va por la opción del SI, este elimine el registro de Firebase y en el listado ya no lo vea.
El problema que tengo es que se elimina el registro de Firebase pero hasta que no reinicio la app la sigo viendo en el listview.

```
// Clase correspondiente al layout "activity_main"
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvSupermarketLists;
    private FloatingActionButton fabAddSupermarketList;

    private ArrayList<ItemList> items;
    private SupermarketListAdapter supermarketListAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Inicializa los atributos
        initialize();

        // Setea al botón para que escuche si le hacen click
        getFabAddSupermarketList().setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
    }

    // Inicializa los atributos
    private void initialize() {
        setFabAddSupermarketList(findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton_addSupermarketList));
        setLvSupermarketLists(findViewById(R.id.listView_lists));
        setItems(new ArrayList<>());

        // Obtiene una instancia de la base de datos y se guarda la referencia a la raíz
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ROOT_REFERENCE);

        // Obtiene los títulos de las listas que estan en la base y los muestra en el listview
        getTitlesAndShowInListView(reference);
    }

    // Getters y Setters
    public ListView getLvSupermarketLists() {
        return this.lvSupermarketLists;
    }

    public void setLvSupermarketLists(ListView lvSupermarketLists) {
        this.lvSupermarketLists = lvSupermarketLists;
    }

    public FloatingActionButton getFabAddSupermarketList() {
        return this.fabAddSupermarketList;
    }

    public void setFabAddSupermarketList(FloatingActionButton fab) {
        this.fabAddSupermarketList = fab;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemList> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }

    public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemList> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public SupermarketListAdapter getSupermarketListAdapter() {
        return this.supermarketListAdapter;
    }



    // Al hacer click en el botón flotante me lleva a la pantalla para crear una nueva lista de supermercado
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddSupermarketListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Obtiene los títulos de las listas que estan en la base y los muestra en el listview
    private void getTitlesAndShowInListView(DatabaseReference reference) {
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            // Creo una lista donde se van a guardar los títulos de las listas que hay en la base
            final ArrayList<String> supermarketLists = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // Para cada elemento de la base
                for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    // Obtengo el título de cada lista
                    Object title = data.child("title").getValue();
                    // Si el título no es null y no lo contiene la lista
                    if (title != null && !supermarketLists.contains(title.toString())) {
                        // Agrego el título a la lista que voy a mostrar en el listview
                        supermarketLists.add(title.toString());
                    }
                }

                // Carga el listview con los nombres de las listas que hay en la base
                showSupermarketLists(supermarketLists);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    // Carga el listview con la lista que recibe de parámetro
    private void showSupermarketLists(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists) {
        setItems(getItemsList(supermarketLists));

        this.supermarketListAdapter = new SupermarketListAdapter(this, getItems());
        getLvSupermarketLists().setAdapter(getSupermarketListAdapter());
    }

    // Crea la lista con los items que va a mostrar en el listview
    private ArrayList<ItemList> getItemsList(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists) {
        ArrayList<ItemList> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String title : supermarketLists) {
            items.add(new ItemList(title, R.drawable.delete));
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

```
public class SupermarketListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList;

    private final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ROOT_REFERENCE);

    public SupermarketListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList) {
        setContext(context);
        setItemsList(itemsList);
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return this.context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemList> getItemsList() {
        return this.itemsList;
    }

    public void setItemsList(ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
    }

    public DatabaseReference getReference() {
        return this.reference;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return getItemsList().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return getItemsList().get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        // Obtengo el item que se hizo click
        ItemList item = (ItemList) getItem(position);

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_title_list,
                    viewGroup,
                    false);
            // Creo los elementos
            ImageButton ibDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_deleteList);
            TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);

            ibDelete.setImageResource(item.getIbDeleteListId());

            // Si se hace click en el botón de eliminar
            ibDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // Abre el Alert Dialog
                showDialog(position, buildMessage(item.getTitle()), item.getTitle());
            });

            // Setea el título de la lista en el textview
            tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

            // Si se hace click en el item
            view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                // Abro la lista

            });
        }

        return view;
    }

    // Muestra el Alert Dialog
    private void showDialog(int position, String message, String title) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setTitle(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.titleDeleteConfirmation))
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    // Crea la query que va a utilizar para obtener la key para eliminar el registro
                    Query query = getReference()
                            .orderByChild("title")
                            .equalTo(title);

                    // Elimina el registro de la base
                    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String key = data.getKey();

                                if (key != null) {
                                  getReference().child(key).removeValue();

                                }
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                        }
                    });
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    // Cierra el dialog y no hace nada
                })
                .show();
    }

    // Crea el mensaje que muestra el Alert Dialog
    private String buildMessage(String title) {
        String message = getContext().getText(R.string.deleteConfirmation).toString();
        message += " ";
        message += title;
        message += getContext().getText(R.string.questionSign).toString();

        return message;
    }

}
```

Intenté borrar desde el adapter el elemento de la lista que hay en el MainActivity, pero el resultado siempre es el mismo.

Comment: Sucede que cuando eliminas el elemento, debes volver a cargar el conjunto de datos, pasarlo a una nueva instancia del adaptador y re-establecer este adaptador a tu `ListView`.

Comment: Yo uso el evento `itemLongClick` del `ListView` para eliminar elementos, eliminandolo del `ArrayList`, creando un nuevo adaptador con el mismo y re-asignandolo al `ListView`.La cuestión acá que que el evento de eliminación se encuentra dentro de tu adaptador, por lo que una opción sería pasar al mismo la instancia de tu actividad, y de esta manera, ser capaz de modificar el `ListView` desde el adaptador.

Comment: La idea es que al hacer click en una parte del registro que no sea el botón, este abra otro activity con los detalles del item seleccionado.

Intente lo que me comentaste (Si entendí bien) y Consigo el mismo resultado que antes.

Estas son las dos líneas que agregue en el adapter:

getMainActivity().getItems().remove(position);
                                  getMainActivity().getLvSupermarketLists().setAdapter(getMainActivity().getSupermarketListAdapter());

Y cuando creo el Adapter en el MainActivity lo paso como MainActivity.this.

Answer (score 1):

Lo pude solucionar.

El problema estaba en el ArrayList auxiliar que usa en el método

```
private void showSupermarketLists(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists)
```

de la MainActivity, ya que nunca eliminaba los datos de esa lista cuando ya cumplió su función.

Al final las clases quedaron de la siguiente manera:

MainActivity

```
// Clase correspondiente al layout "activity_main"
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lvSupermarketLists;
private FloatingActionButton fabAddSupermarketList;

private ArrayList<ItemList> items;
private ArrayList<String> supermarketLists;
private SupermarketListAdapter supermarketListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Inicializa los atributos
    initialize();

    // Setea al botón para que escuche si le hacen click
    getFabAddSupermarketList().setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
}

// Inicializa los atributos
private void initialize() {
    setFabAddSupermarketList(findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton_addSupermarketList));
    setLvSupermarketLists(findViewById(R.id.listView_lists));
    setItems(new ArrayList<>());
    setSupermarketLists(new ArrayList<>());

    // Obtiene una instancia de la base de datos y se guarda la referencia a la raíz
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ROOT_REFERENCE);

    // Obtiene los títulos de las listas que estan en la base y los muestra en el listview
    getTitlesAndShowInListView(reference);
}

// Getters y Setters
public ListView getLvSupermarketLists() {
    return this.lvSupermarketLists;
}

public void setLvSupermarketLists(ListView lvSupermarketLists) {
    this.lvSupermarketLists = lvSupermarketLists;
}

public FloatingActionButton getFabAddSupermarketList() {
    return this.fabAddSupermarketList;
}

public void setFabAddSupermarketList(FloatingActionButton fab) {
    this.fabAddSupermarketList = fab;
}

public ArrayList<ItemList> getItems() {
    return this.items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<ItemList> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

public ArrayList<String> getSupermarketLists() {
    return this.supermarketLists;
}

public void setSupermarketLists(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists) {
    this.supermarketLists = supermarketLists;
}

public SupermarketListAdapter getSupermarketListAdapter() {
    return this.supermarketListAdapter;
}

// Al hacer click en el botón flotante me lleva a la pantalla para crear una nueva lista de supermercado
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddSupermarketListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Obtiene los títulos de las listas que estan en la base y los muestra en el listview
private void getTitlesAndShowInListView(DatabaseReference reference) {
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        // Creo una lista donde se van a guardar los títulos de las listas que hay en la base
        //final ArrayList<String> supermarketLists = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // Para cada elemento de la base
            for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                // Obtengo el título de cada lista
                Object title = data.child("title").getValue();
                // Si el título no es null y no lo contiene la lista
                if (title != null && !getSupermarketLists().contains(title.toString())) {
                    // Agrego el título a la lista que voy a mostrar en el listview
                    getSupermarketLists().add(title.toString());
                }
            }

            // Carga el listview con los nombres de las listas que hay en la base
            showSupermarketLists(getSupermarketLists());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}

// Carga el listview con la lista que recibe de parámetro
private void showSupermarketLists(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists) {
    setItems(getItemsList(supermarketLists));

    this.supermarketListAdapter = new SupermarketListAdapter(this, getItems());
    getLvSupermarketLists().setAdapter(getSupermarketListAdapter());
}

// Crea la lista con los items que va a mostrar en el listview
private ArrayList<ItemList> getItemsList(ArrayList<String> supermarketLists) {
    ArrayList<ItemList> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String title : supermarketLists) {
        items.add(new ItemList(title, R.drawable.delete));
    }
    getSupermarketLists().clear();
    return items;
}
}
```

SupermarketListAdapter

```
// Adaptador para el listview que muestra las listas en el MainActivity
public class SupermarketListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList;

private final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private final DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.ROOT_REFERENCE);

public SupermarketListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList) {
    setContext(context);
    setItemsList(itemsList);
}

public Context getContext() {
    return this.context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public ArrayList<ItemList> getItemsList() {
    return this.itemsList;
}

public void setItemsList(ArrayList<ItemList> itemsList) {
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
}

public DatabaseReference getReference() {
    return this.reference;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return getItemsList().size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return getItemsList().get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // Obtengo el item que se hizo click
    ItemList item = (ItemList) getItem(position);

    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_title_list,
                viewGroup,
                false);
        // Creo los elementos
        ImageButton ibDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_deleteList);
        TextView tvTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);

        ibDelete.setImageResource(item.getIbDeleteListId());

        // Si se hace click en el botón de eliminar
        ibDelete.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Abre el Alert Dialog
            showDialog(position, buildMessage(item.getTitle()), item.getTitle());
        });

        // Setea el título de la lista en el textview
        tvTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

        // Si se hace click en el item
        view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Abro la lista

        });
    }

    return view;
}

// Muestra el Alert Dialog
private void showDialog(int position, String message, String title) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setTitle(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.titleDeleteConfirmation))
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                // Crea la query que va a utilizar para obtener la key para eliminar el registro
                Query query = getReference()
                        .orderByChild("title")
                        .equalTo(title);

                // Elimina el registro de la base
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot data : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String key = data.getKey();

                            if (key != null) {
                              getReference().child(key).removeValue();
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                // Cierra el dialog y no hace nada
            })
            .show();
}

// Crea el mensaje que muestra el Alert Dialog
private String buildMessage(String title) {
    String message = getContext().getText(R.string.deleteConfirmation).toString();
    message += " ";
    message += title;
    message += getContext().getText(R.string.questionSign).toString();

    return message;
}

}
```